# How do i find a plane equation of a plane that is perpendicular to another plane and intersects line l?

Tags: calculus

This is the question d) in my assignment:

**Question**

I was given a point $M=(1,0,-1)$ and Line $L$ in plane intersect form (I hope that is the correct English term) $L:{3x+y+z-4=0,x+y-z-2=0}$;
given line $L:(1,1,0)+t(-1,2,1)$
and plane: $P: x+y-z-2=0$ (which was found as a plane that intersects point M and line L)

How do I find plane T such that plane T intersects line l and is perpendicular to plane P?

Comment: I am not sure i understood the question tho, in my language its written as the plane "goes through" line L and perpendicular to plane P,

Comment: Please use MathJax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're looking for a plane $T$ which *contains* line $L$ and is perpendicular to plane $P$.

A normal vector of plane $P$ can be read off from the coefficients: $n_P=(1,1,-1)$, now for a normal vector of $T$ just take the cross product of $n_P$ and the direction vector of $L$: $(-1,2,1)$, and finally use that $(1,1,0)\in T$ to find the constant term in the equation of $T$.

Comment: Thank you sir, apparently the grammar of the question was a bit wierd.. i did what you said and it makes a lot of sense. Much appreciated!